# How can I get the client username from the Active Directory after I published on IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, active-directory, windows-server-2022

I have an Angular frontend and ASP.NET backend, I published the site on IIS 10, I also created a Windows Server 2022 Virtual Machine in Hyper-V. Right now I can access the site from the external PC, but I don't want to use login prompt in chrome.

I just need the actual Windows username from the client side. On the backend I enabled anonymous authentication, on the frontend there is windows authentication. I tried to swap these settings and then from the backend I tried to read the username, but the backend runs on the server, not on the client PC.

Comment: *I just need* - this needs clarification. Your frontend needs or your backend needs. The frontend username or the backend username.

Comment: If you want to implement single sign-on (SSO) between your Angular frontend and your ASP.NET backend, perhaps you can use Auth0 to authenticate and implement SSO. https://community.auth0.com/t/sso-between-a-net-core-2-0-mvc-and-angular-application/12502

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As I know Angular frontend doesn't have access to the Windows username without client permission. My challenge is that I want to avoid presenting any login prompts to clients. Ideally, when they open my webpage, I'd like the current Windows username and password to be automatically passed without requiring them to input. I am using chrome.

Comment: Web browsers prioritize security and privacy, so it is not advisable to gain access to a user's Windows username and password without the user's explicit consent or interaction. Passing Windows usernames and passwords automatically without user input raises serious security and privacy concerns and may be considered intrusive and potentially harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Windows Authentication, which will give you the username in the backend in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Then, from there, you can insert the username (or whatever other information you need) into your frontend code.

To prevent the browser from prompting for credentials, you need to add the URL to the Trusted Sites in the Windows Internet Options on each client computer. This can be done by Group Policy. That will tell Chrome and Edge to send the user credentials automatically. If your organization uses Firefox, it has its own setting for this.